# $C_0^\infty(R)$ metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I found the statement that the space $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is not metrizable:

see for example Remark 27 here:
http://www.math.mcgill.ca/gantumur/math581w14/distrib.pdf
or one of the answers here:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52032/examples-of-non-metrizable-spaces

On the other hand, $\|f\|:=sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|$ defines a norm on this space and therefore the space is a metric space. But, as far as I know, every metric space is metrizable which is a contradiction to the statement above that the space of continuous and compactly supported functions is not metrizable.

Am I misunderstanding something? Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Metrizability is a property of topological spaces. A priori you are just considering a set $C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R})$. With the uniform norm on it, this is of course metrizable, but that is not the usual topology on the space of test functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with you: the property of being metrizable doesnt make any sense If I dont specify the topology. But this is indeed the case in the lecture notes above which is also a reason why I was confused.

So my next question is: it doesnt make sense to talk about metrizability if the corresponding topology is not specified, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are missing is the context in which the statement is being made. Notice that the notes you linked to your question are about [Distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function#Schwartz_distributions). In the later link, it is implicit that they are referring to "test" functions in the theory of distributions

In the theory of distributions, it is understood (certainly not for those who study this for the first time) that $\mathcal{C}^\infty_0$, which is then denoted as $\mathcal{D}$ and called **test functions**, is assigned an **inductive limit topology** -not easy to digest the first time arround- that make it a locally convex complete linear space.

Although the topology is not metrizable, its raison d'etre is to justify the nice properties of its dual (the **space of distributions** or generalized functions), some of which which were in used in Physics long before they were rigorously justified. Distributions (and its cousin, tempered distributions), it turns out,  is a  great tool (or the right tool) to solve and analyze  some partial differential equations (PDEs).

Comment: Thanks very much! That means that indeed this specific topology is assumed in the above references (implicitly). This brings light into the darkness... Thanks!

Comment: @Frank. Thus, with the statement "the space $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is not metrizable" one means that the topology normally used for this space can not be given by a metrics. A set without a given topology can always be assigned a metrics and an induced topology; just set $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\neq y$ and $d(x,x)=0.$ This gives the discrete topology.

Comment: The statement as such is not meaningful without context. The notation $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ gives context and then one knows what we are talking about: the space of infinite differentiable functions with compact support on the real line ($C^\infty_{00}(\mathbb{R})$ with the inductive limit topology. On any uncountable  set $X$  we can define a topology which is not metrizable. The usefulness of such topology is a different story.